# Non-blocking/async Spring MVC server: designing an API for long-running REST requests

Tags: java, rest, http, spring-mvc

I'm learning about RX Java and Spring MVC and see we can have ‘asynchronous/non-blocking' request processing flow in a REST server.

Using Spring's DeferredResult type and RxJava Observable pattern gives a non-blocking thread model in the server which seems a good thing.  Some info on non-blocking REST services with Spring MVC  [here](http://www.java-allandsundry.com/2015/03/using-rx-java-observable-in-spring-mvc.html) and [here](http://callistaenterprise.se/blogg/teknik/2014/04/22/c10k-developing-non-blocking-rest-services-with-spring-mvc/)

However I am unclear when REST jobs or requests are *long enough* to require the pattern where the REST server responds immediately and does the work after the initial HTTP request completes.

http://farazdagi.com/blog/2014/rest-long-running-jobs/ shows a response like

```
± http POST https://api.service.io/stars name='Death Star’
HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
Location: /queue/12345
```

This is described in detail at http://restcookbook.com/Resources/asynchroneous-operations/

I presume [this async REST pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33009721/long-running-rest-api-with-queues) is needed to avoid clients having overlong HTTP requests and/or many blocked server-threads but in a world where the server is non-blocking, is it okay to have *a bit longer running* REST requests than before ?

Where to draw the line - is it seconds or minutes? And with sharing of connections, e.g http pipe-lining, can this be extended further?

Comment: ...always milliseconds and/or seconds - not minutes